# After removing VDAgent Spice Ubuntu won't boot

Tags: boot, grub2, spice

As the title says, I can't boot. Instead I get a black screen with a bunch of words I do not understand.

What I have done to attempt fixing:

1. I noticed that if I go to advanced options in the GRUB that there is Ubuntu 18.04.05 and Ubuntu 18.04.06 so, assuming I tried launching the version 5. This yielded the same result
2. I went it to safe mode and updated the GRUB, repaired packages with network activated then relaunched. It was just a blank screen so i used power button to reboot, and then got the same screen.

[The words I do not understand.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01mEn.jpg)

[continued...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wtzo.jpg)

Please help.

Comment: No. In fact it's completely unrelated, I just mentioned I see multiple options in my GRUB.